# Which blocking session is shown in Oracle 12c in V$SESSION, when wait event is "enq: TX - allocate ITL entry"?

Tags: oracle, locking

We created a testcase on Oracle 12.1 as consequence of totally stucking application because of endless
"enq: TX - allocate ITL entry" in a scenario with about 50 parallel processes. Each of them do the same type of update:

`UPDATE MYTAB SET CHARGE=:1 WHERE USAGE=:2 AND CHARGE IS NULL;`

During analysis, we detected multiple sessions, showing in V$SESSION.BLOCKING_SESSION any other SID, that holds an open TX.
However, this is usually clear for e.g. row-lock contention, where another session holds exactly this particular row and the blocking session can distinctively be identified.

In our case, we forced the same situation by reducing PCT_FREE to 0 with reorg, because the lock was caused by "enq: TX - allocate ITL entry", which is clearly waiting for a free ITL-Slot in block-header. By reducing PCTFREE, there is not enough free space for dynamically allocating additionally ITL-Entries, which forces this kind of ITL-lock.
Since increasing INITRANS is due to the high number of 50 parallel independend threads no perfect solution, I would like to understand the situation more detailed.

However, since there can be multiple ITL-Slots and so multiple transactions having uncommitted data in this block, the question is, which one is shown in V$SESSION.BLOCKING_SESSION? Just the first matching? Or the oldest? Or any other criteria?
The answer would help us to get a better understanding of the situation.

BTW: We have meanwhile almost understood, that Oracle's deadlock detection cannot work properly, because the lock-chain is partially outsourced to the application, where another session does similar work on same objects with other sessions, which finally creates an endless deadlock via Application, but this is another story...

Comment: You *might* be able to solve the problem by increasing the value of `INITRANS` physical attribute of the table to be larger than the default of 2.

Comment: I know that, haven't mentioned it myself, but thanks. I'll update the question.
The idea of my question was more to understand the sequence of lockings and so to understand more detailed about the whole situation.